# How to pass javascript textBox value to URL as parameter

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, textbox

I would like to pass the value from a date and time picker as a parameter to a URL. This is what I have:

```
<div style="text-align:left; margin:8px 5px auto;">
        <label for="dt_id">Please enter a date and time </label>
        <input type="Text" id="dt_id" maxlength="25" size="25"/>
        <img src="../../js/datetimepicker/images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('dt_id','yyyyMMdd','arrow','true','24')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
        <input type='button' onclick='setURL()' value='SUBMIT'> 
</div>

<script>
var dt_value = document.getElementById("dt_id").value;
var sjdurl =  "/path/script?datetime="+dt_value;
</script>
```

However, the URL does not include the date value.

Comment: your JS code should be inside setURL() function..

Comment: I would check with alert(dt_value) or console.log(dt_value) to see if you're picking up the value at all first, then go from there.

Comment: Also, does something appear in the URL at all or nothing? You may need to be using encodeURI and decodeURI [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI ]

Answer (score 4):

i tried to reproduce the scenario and it was completely working for me :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function setURL(){
    var dt_value = document.getElementById("dt_id").value;
    //just test here ..what is coming..
    alert(dt_value );
    var sjdurl =  "www.google.com?datetime="+dt_value;

popup = window.open(sjdurl,"popup"," menubar =0,toolbar =0,location=0, height=900, width=1000"); 
popup.window.moveTo(950,150); 

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:left; margin:8px 5px auto;">
        <label for="dt_id">Please enter a date and time </label>
        <input type="Text" id="dt_id" maxlength="25" size="25"/>
        <input type='button' onclick='setURL()' value='SUBMIT'> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention: I am using the url in  popup function : popup = window.open(sjdurl,"popup"," menubar =0,toolbar =0,location=0, height=900, width=1000"); I have also used the alert(dt_value) to check and the value is correct!

Comment: sjd.node.onclick = function () {
              popup = window.open(sjdurl,"popup"," menubar =0,toolbar =0,location=0, height=900, width=1000");
              popup.window.moveTo(950,150);
              if (window.focus){popup.focus};
             };

Comment: Two thing :- 1> how you are setting the var sjdurl, inside a setURL function or globally. if inside a SetURL function then how you are accessing that variable in openpopup function because it will be out of scope.2> if globally then how you are setting the variable.?

Comment: Problem Solved. My onclick function was outside of the setURL function.

Comment: very good if it is solved ..but if my answer has helped you then you should Vote up and accept the answer.